# How to create constructor with arrow functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple menu toggle functionality with JavaScript. And I am using constructors with functions to achieve it like below:

**Constructor with anonymous function:**

```js
(function(){
  // Constructor
  function Menu(selector){
      let menu = document.querySelector(selector);
      return {
          activateToggle: function(){
              menu.addEventListener("click", function(){
                  menu.parentNode.querySelector("ul").classList.toggle("hidden");
              });
          },
          default: function(){
              menu.parentNode.querySelector("ul").classList.add("hidden");
          }
      }
  }

  let topMenu = new Menu(".burger");
  topMenu.default();
  topMenu.activateToggle();
  let bottomMenu = new Menu(".bottom-burger");
  bottomMenu.activateToggle();
})();
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!--Top Menu-->
<div class="topmenu">
    <button class="burger">Top Menu</button>
    <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li><li>Item 5</li></ul>
</div>
<!--Bottom Menu-->
<div class="bottommenu">
    <button class="bottom-burger">Bottom Menu</button>
    <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li><li>Item 5</li></ul>
</div>
```

**Same Menu with arrow function:**

```js
(function(){
    // Constructor
    let Menu = (selector) => {
        let menu = document.querySelector(selector);
        return {
            activateToggle: () => menu.addEventListener("click", () => menu.parentNode.querySelector("ul").classList.toggle("hidden")),
            default: () => menu.parentNode.querySelector("ul").classList.add("hidden")
        }
    }

    let topMenu = new Menu(".burger");
    topMenu.default();
    topMenu.activateToggle();
    let bottomMenu = new Menu(".bottom-burger");
    bottomMenu.activateToggle();
})();
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!--Top Menu-->
<div class="topmenu">
    <button class="burger">Top Menu</button>
    <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li><li>Item 5</li></ul>
</div>
<!--Bottom Menu-->
<div class="bottommenu">
    <button class="bottom-burger">Bottom Menu</button>
    <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li><li>Item 5</li></ul>
</div>
```

The above code throws an error **`"Menu is not a constructor"`**. I have tried to find the answer on how to create constructor with arrow functions but most of the article says that we can not use `new` keyword with arrow function.

Then what is the correct approach to create constructor with arrow functions?

Comment: Yes, arrow functions cannot be used as constructors. If you want to avoid `function`s, use `class`es.

Comment: Just drop the `new` keywords and you're good to go. Your functions never really were constructors anyway, they're factory functions.

Comment: Arrow function are not just syntax, the actual function is different in important ways, and cannot be used with `new`. 1. They *close over* `this`, so even if they could be used with `new`, they wouldn't have access to the new instance in order to set properties on it. 2. They don't have the `[[Construct]]` internal feature that constructors must have. 3. They don't have the `prototype` property that constructor functions must have. But as Bergi points out: Your functions aren't constructors anyway!

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks a lot for the clarification. Will have a look at classes.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. Makes sense now. It is just a straight forward function call then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions (even your traditional `function` functions) aren't constructor functions, they're *builder* functions; you shouldn't use `new` with them in the first place. A *constructor* function sets properties on `this` and such and doesn't issue a `return` statement. Your functions build their own objects (no need for `new`) and return them.

And since you shouldn't use `new` with them, it's just fine to make them arrow functions. Arrow functions can't be constructor functions, but they can be builders.

When a function is a builder and not a constructor, overwhelmingly it shouldn't start with a capital letter. So for instance, `createMenu` rather than `Menu`. Here's your code with that change and without `new`:

```js
(function(){
    // Constructor
    let createMenu = (selector) => {
        let menu = document.querySelector(selector);
        return {
            activateToggle: () => menu.addEventListener("click", () => menu.parentNode.querySelector("ul").classList.toggle("hidden")),
            default: () => menu.parentNode.querySelector("ul").classList.add("hidden")
        }
    }

    let topMenu = createMenu(".burger");
    topMenu.default();
    topMenu.activateToggle();
    let bottomMenu = createMenu(".bottom-burger");
    bottomMenu.activateToggle();
})();
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!--Top Menu-->
<div class="topmenu">
    <button class="burger">Top Menu</button>
    <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li><li>Item 5</li></ul>
</div>
<!--Bottom Menu-->
<div class="bottommenu">
    <button class="bottom-burger">Bottom Menu</button>
    <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li><li>Item 5</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have been using new with all my anonymous functions with properties set via this keyword, for almost all my projects. Seems unnecessary then.

Comment: @KiranDash - Both styles are in common use in the JavaScript world. There's a bit more syntactic support for constructor functions than builders thanks to `class` syntax (which creates constructor functions and prototypical chains), but you can do much the same with builder functions and `Object.create` (to create prototype chains).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would structure with a class based approach:

```
class Menu {
    constructor (selector) {
    this.topMenu = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.parentUl = this.topMenu.parentNode.querySelector("ul");
    this.init();
  }
  init() {
    this.menu.addEventListener('click', this.toggleHiddenState.bind(this));
  }
  toggleHiddenState(e) {
    this.parentUl.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
  hide() {
    this.parentUl.classList.add("hidden");
  }

}

// Usage
let topmenu = new Menu('.burger');
topmenu.hide();

let bottomMenu = new Menu('.bottom-burger');
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the class approach as well.